# Unity C# why color of prefab child does not change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my unity project I have a prefab with many child objects. If I click on a button, I want that some child objects from the prefab change their color. Unfortunately with my code nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
public class ColorChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject preFabParent;
    public GameObject preFabChildTarget

    public Material newColor;

    Renderer[] prefabChildrenParent, prefabChildren;

    bool changePrefabColor;

    void Start()
    {
        prefabChildrenParent = preFabParent.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
        prefabChildren = preFabChildTarget.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // bool is changed by a button click:
        if(changePrefabColor) ChangeColor();
    }

    void ChangeColor()
    {
        // Now I want that all the child objects from the prefabChildTarget get the new color.
        foreach(Renderer child in prefabChildren)
        {
            var mats = new Material[child.sharedMaterials.Length];
            for(var j = 0; j < child.sharedMaterials.Length, j++)
            {
                mats[j] = newColor;
            }
            child.sharedMaterials = mats;
        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to change that my code will work? Unfortunately I could not find a solution which works for me.

Comment: surely you want to change the instantiated object, not the prefab

Comment: I guess the name prefab is not chosen wisely here ... Prefab usually refers to a template object only existing in the Assets not instantiated in the scene. Please make clear what you are referring to ... If it is an object in the scene please chose another field name for it like e.g. `target` or anything that is not `prefab` ;)

Comment: @BugFinder I did it wrong .. I changed the code now .. this is what I really want to do

Comment: @derHugo okay .. i will change my code again and hope it will be clear after that

Comment: well still: Are you really talking about a **prefab** or are you trying to change the color of objects existing in the Scene?

Comment: @derHugo I try to change the color of objects existing in the scene.

Comment: I am pretty sure this would work if you use child.Materials instead of child.sharedMaterials. This will also make sure that it wont change materials in other objects, as sharedMaterials is (as the name suggests) shared with multiple instances of the prefab.

Comment: @BartKuijer if I use child.materials I get this error `Not allowed to access Renderer.materials on prefab object. Use Renderer.sharedMaterials instead`

Comment: What did you drag into preFabChildTarget in the inspector? an object from the scene or an object from the assetfolder?

Comment: @BartKuijer into `preFabTarget` I dragged an object from the asset/prefab folder

Comment: @diem_L well then your comment `I try to change the color of objects existing in the scene.` is not true ... If you instantiate this object somewhere rather do it on this created object's reference

Comment: @derHugo yeah, there was a misunderstanding on my side .. sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how your error is

```
Not allowed to access Renderer.materials on prefab object. Use Renderer.sharedMaterials instead
```

I am pretty sure that you are referencing an object in the assets folder and not an instantiated object in the scene. Make sure you reference an object in the scene and the issue should be solved.

Comment: i do not have any objects in my scene, all my object were created by prefabs if I hit play or switch to this scene. This is why I dragged the prefab to `preFabTarget`

Comment: you can add this script on the prefab and then reference the objects in the prefab from the prefab editor. that way each instance of the prefab will be created with this script linking to its objects.

Comment: adding the script to the prefab solved the problem .. thanks a lot :)